# Android text input layout

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a text input layout and I want to use that to show an error message if the data entered in an edit text inside it is incorrect. The definitions are as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/number_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabelWhite" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/number_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:digits="01234 56789"
                android:hint="Number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The style is defined as follows:

```
<style name="TextLabelWhite" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Now if the data entered is not correct I do the following operations:

```
TextInputLayout numberInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.number_input_layout);
EditText numberEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);
numberEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
numberInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
numberEditText.setError("Tis an error dear");
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

When all of this is done I get the error:

`Can't convert to color: type=0x2` on the line `numberInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);`

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT 1: As soon as I remove the `TextLabelWhite` theme, it starts working. But the theme is necessary.

Comment: `numberEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#Your_Hex_code"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);`

Comment: `EditText numberEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya why is this method correct and why will it work?

Comment: instead of getView(), use view. Like:-
EditText numberEditText=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);

Comment: @Dorami tried. Still not working.

Comment: is this intentional or a typo? "<item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>" compared to the other three lines: no 'android'

Comment: @0X0nosugar I have edited to just say colors now, still no joy.

Answer (score 16):

Change

```
android:theme="@style/TextLabelWhite"
```

to

```
style="@style/TextLabelWhite"
```

in android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout attributes in your xml, and you will not got an error.

**UPDATE:** To customize colors you can try this. Add

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/white</item>
```

directly to your **app theme** style. It'll affect on all EditText, but if it's not a problem for your app it may helps.

**UPDATE 2:**

The best solution i've found. Use

```
android:theme="@style/TextLabelWhite"
```

just like in your xml. Change TextLabelWhite style parent to your AppTheme style, like:

```
<style name="TextLabelWhite" parent="AppTheme">
```

But android:textColorHint will not work on TextInputLayout (have no such attribute). You should use [design:hintTextAppearance](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:hintTextAppearance), but place it in different style and apply directly to TextInputLayout via

```
design:hintTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearance"
```

Comment: Tried, the theme is not applied and the style tag doesn't really work, in short I end up with the default `edittext` colors.

Answer (score 2):

At first call `view` instead of `getView()`

**Don't**

```
EditText numberEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);
```

**Do**

```
EditText numberEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);
```

Comment: Could you  explain why this is correct and why it will work?

Comment: Also, tried this, didn't work. Are you sure this is what is needed?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava i assume problem is here `android:theme="@style/TextLabelWhite"`

Comment: Yup, the moment I remove it, everything goes fine. But the theme is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try This Once and do lemme know: 
**without TextInputLayout**

```
EditText numberEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);

String strNumber  = shipText.getText().toString();
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strNumber  )) {
                    numberEditText .setError("Please enter a value");

                 }
```

Or Do :
**with TextInputLayout**

```
TextInputLayout numberInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.number_input_layout);
EditText numberEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);
**numberInputLayout.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);**
numberInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
***numberInputLayout.setError("Tis an error dear");***
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```