# Android Studio errors when running on a hardware device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, galaxy

I tried to run the default "hello world" program, in apk 17, onto my hardware device, a SAMSUNG Galaxy s3 that runs apk 19 (KitKat). My program works perfectly on an APK 21 emulator, but the app loads on my device for a split second and then crashes. I am sure that I got the right driver, as when I click the "run" button, the name of my device shows up and it can communicate with my device. It is definitely in USB debugging mode, and I have already tried revoking authorization and giving it back to my computer to no avail. Maybe I;m using an out of date version of gradle or something?

Here is the crash log:

```
10/31 20:43:14: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\G\AndroidStudioProjects\HappyBirthday\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.happybirthday
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.happybirthday"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.happybirthday
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.android.happybirthday/com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 30844 on device samsung-sph_l710t-b3849b78
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.android.happybirthday, real application class is null.
W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15997: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15999: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16003: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 685: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 707: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <vector>
                      org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportHeight > 0
                          at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:544)
                          at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:478)
                          at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:441)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:742)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:362)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:720)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
                          at com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10)
                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b38da0)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.android.happybirthday, PID: 30844
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.happybirthday/com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3066)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1627)
                      at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:720)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
                      at com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                   Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:986)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3062)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1627) 
                      at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:720) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190) 
                      at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71) 
                      at com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30844 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with using `<vector>` in `abc_vector_test.xml` for a pre-21 device.. have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663413/xmlpullparserexception-binary-xml-file-line-17vector-tag-requires-viewportwid) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819290/invalid-drawable-tag-vector) and confirmed that your setup is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Disable instant run for the project, clean and run the project again, it will work.

Comment: I tried it again, and it's still crashing. The exceptions as listed above are identical, although lines 3 and 4 from the error code about instant run are gone.

Answer (score 0):

First check your drawable resource and make sure that abc_vector_test.xml exist there ,then go to your project's work-space and delete the build folder under the app folder then rebuild the project.

Comment: abc_vector_test.xml does not exist anywhere within the project. I tried deleting the build folders, but all that did was have the computer rebuild it and the app still crashed. It works for the emulator though, maybe kitkat isn't compatible with android studio anymore?