# app getting crashed and i am not able to understand it

Tags: android

Firstly, i got index exception and after invalidating cache my app crashed , please help? I have attached logcat and build.gradle file. Its giving error in main activity though the code is right there.

**Logcat:**

```
15793-15793/com.example.user.e_mart E/VdcInflateDelegate﹕ Exception while inflating <vector>
        org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
                at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:535)
                at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:472)
                at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:829)
                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:303)
                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:178)
                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
                at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
                at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
                at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:226)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createViewFromTag(AppCompatViewInflater.java:175)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:146)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:963)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1022)
                at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                at com.example.user.e_mart.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-27 15:39:33.032  15793-15793/com.example.user.e_mart E/test﹕ Exception
    02-27 15:39:33.036  15793-15793/com.example.user.e_mart E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.e_mart/com.example.user.e_mart.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                at com.example.user.e_mart.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                at com.example.user.e_mart.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1998)
                at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:678)
                at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48)
                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374)
                at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44)
                at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
                at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
                at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
                at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                at com.example.user.e_mart.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:920)
                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:852)
                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1995)
                at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:678)
                at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48)
                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374)
                at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44)
                at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
                at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
                at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
                at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                at com.example.user.e_mart.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

**Gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.e_mart"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

}
```

Comment: post build.gradle file

Comment: i have added @Harshad, please check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Android Support Library to 23.2.0 cause error: XmlPullParserException Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622438/update-android-support-library-to-23-2-0-cause-error-xmlpullparserexception-bin)

Comment: so @MarcinJędrzejewski what should i do know, please suggest.

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this problem by replacing

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I got this same error in Android Studio 2.2 after I updated my Gradle dependencies to the latest versions but forgot to update the buildToolsVersion of my project.

I changed:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
```

While buildToolsVersion remained at "22.0.1" like so:

```
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

So all I did was to update the buildToolsVersion to 24 like so:

```
buildToolsVersion "24"
```

since it has previously been download with SDK Manager. So check the latest `Android SDK Build Tools` version from SDK Manager and see if it matches the dependencies version.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ajinkya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2009899/ajinkya) (as found https://stackoverflow.com/a/35624744), you can do the following:

> Use this code in your **build.gradle file**
>
> ```
>    //for Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
>  android {  
>    defaultConfig {  
>      vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
>     }  
>  }
> ```
>
> If you are using **Gradle 1.5 you’ll instead use**
>
> ```
> defaultConfig {
>         generatedDensities = []
>     }
>
>     // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
>     aaptOptions {
>         additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
>     }
> ```
>
> I think may be they are using vector draw-able compact underneath in
> other lib.found [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

For more detail visit Here :  [Update Android Support Library to 23.2.0 cause error: XmlPullParserException Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622438/update-android-support-library-to-23-2-0-cause-error-xmlpullparserexception-bin)

### For Error(8.0)

Renamed a few properties to make things more consistent:

- BuildType.runProguard -> minifyEnabled
- BuildType.zipAlign -> zipAlignEnabled
- BuildType.jniDebugBuild -> jniDebuggable
- BuildType.renderscriptDebug -> renderscriptDebuggable
- ProductFlavor.renderscriptSupportMode ->
  renderscriptSupportModeEnabled
- ProductFlavor.renderscriptNdkMode -> renderscriptNdkModeEnabled

so renderscriptSupportMode rename to renderscriptNdkModeEnabled

Comment: Error:(8, 0) Could not find property 'vectorDrawables' on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.

Comment: buildTypes{release{ minifyEnabled flase}} here.

Comment: Please be very explicit about the parts of your answer you have taken from elsewhere. For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try with changing styles.xml to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

This is because if style requires ActionBar there are chances of not finding abc_back button but with no action bar problem is solved