# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.widget.Toolbar;
    import com.tablayout.SlidingTabLayout;
    import com.tablayout.ViewPagerAdapter;

    public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        Toolbar toolbar;
        ViewPager pager;
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
        SlidingTabLayout tabs;
        CharSequence Titles[] = { "Gallery", "Buy", "Project" };
        int Numboftabs = 3;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.hide();

            adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles,
                    Numboftabs);

            pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

            tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
                @Override
                public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {

                    return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);

                }
            });

            tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        }

    }` 



    and this is my xml file 


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#331c57"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/gappshapp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/threedots" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/callsplus" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/searchicon" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.tablayout.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#cecece"
                android:elevation="2dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>`


    Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

       My app crashes in the Home activity 


   I jst updated the sdk manager
the Android Support Library and import the  android-support-v7-appcompact again and use it in my project but it still have the issue

 how to solve this issue? 

I m tired of this problem, please help me out....


my configure build file is
```

[image]

and my sdk manager is here

[image]

```
    `
```

i change my target in project property file also to 23  and also in library android support v7 appcompact project property 
now what kind of change i have do to remove this issue..

plase help me out from this issue

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622438/update-android-support-library-to-23-2-0-cause-error-xmlpullparserexception-bin

Comment: Use style <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style> for your activity

Comment: I m using eclipse here

Comment: did you initialize `toolbar` in your java class first ?

Comment: it shows up here in this code. i initialize toolbar  and i uses custom class for Tab Layout

Comment: this code working properly, it crashes after i update the sdk manager and it changes  the appcompat-v7 library to android-support-v7-appcompat library name and change target version.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Support Library your App theme needs to extend a `Theme.AppCompat` style.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And in the Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.app">

    <application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And you are also recreating the `Toolbar` yourself with `LinearLayout`s. The purpose of the new `Toolbar` is to be able to be included in the layout and still offer the back/menu button and options menu functionality.

You should include the `Toolbar` in your layout like its explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html#add-toolbar)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```