# App keeps crashing. Works on Galaxy s5 but not s4. Music Player

Tags: android, listview, mediastore, audio-player

so I am creating a music player. The application is working fine on the samsung galaxy s5 but not the s4. The minimum is set for android 4.0. my device is 4.4.4 but it is not working. log cat says something about the binary xml file.

Here is the Log Cat

```
03-17 17:06:36.987  11870-11870/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority [3] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SGH-M919_4.4.4_0048
03-17 17:06:36.987  11870-11870/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
03-17 17:06:36.987  11870-11870/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.example.joe.projectmanhattan [ userId:0 | appId:10239 ]
03-17 17:06:36.987  11870-11870/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-17 17:06:37.127  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-17 17:06:37.127  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
03-17 17:06:37.127  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15026: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-17 17:06:37.127  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-17 17:06:37.127  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
03-17 17:06:37.127  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15030: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-17 17:06:37.127  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-17 17:06:37.177  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-17 17:06:37.177  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 396: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-17 17:06:37.177  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-17 17:06:37.177  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-17 17:06:37.177  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 418: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-17 17:06:37.177  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-17 17:06:37.187  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan E/VdcInflateDelegate﹕ Exception while inflating <vector>
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
            at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:535)
            at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:472)
            at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:829)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:303)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:178)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:379)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
            at com.example.joe.projectmanhattan.ArtistList.onCreate(ArtistList.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 17:06:37.187  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-17 17:06:37.187  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41845da0)
03-17 17:06:37.187  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.joe.projectmanhattan, PID: 11870
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.joe.projectmanhattan/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan.ArtistList}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:379)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
            at com.example.joe.projectmanhattan.ArtistList.onCreate(ArtistList.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:379)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
            at com.example.joe.projectmanhattan.ArtistList.onCreate(ArtistList.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v19/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3439)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1893)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44)
            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:379)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
            at com.example.joe.projectmanhattan.ArtistList.onCreate(ArtistList.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:986)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3435)
    .
03-17 17:06:39.920  11870-11870/com.example.joe.projectmanhattan I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 11870 SIG: 9
```

Here is my List for the artist and songs

```
    package com.example.joe.projectmanhattan;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArtistList extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mp3List;

    String title, artist, path, displayName, songDuration,album;
    ArrayList<Mp3Model> Artist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_artist_list);

        mp3List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.artist_list);
        Artist = new ArrayList<>();

        scanSdcard();

        SongAdapter adapter = new SongAdapter(this, Artist);
        mp3List.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void scanSdcard() {
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
        };
        final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                    Mp3Model mp3Model = new Mp3Model();

                    title = cursor.getString(0);
                    artist = cursor.getString(1);
                    path = cursor.getString(2);
                    displayName = cursor.getString(3);
                    songDuration = cursor.getString(4);
                    album=cursor.getString(5);

                    mp3Model.setTitle(title);
                    mp3Model.setArtist(artist);
                    mp3Model.setPath(path);
                    mp3Model.setDisplayName(displayName);
                    mp3Model.setSongDuration(songDuration);
                    //needs album in mp3model

                    Artist.add(mp3Model);

                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Tag", e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}


here is the my Adapter:

    package com.example.joe.projectmanhattan;

/**
 * Created by joe on 3/17/2016.
 */
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import static android.graphics.Color.*;

/**
 * Created by joe on 3/3/2016.
 */
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Mp3Model> mp3Models;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    //Typeface captureFont;

    public SongAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Mp3Model> mp3Models) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mp3Models = mp3Models;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //captureFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.context.getAssets(), "fonts/verdana.ttf");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mp3Models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView songName;
        TextView artistName;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.audio_list_style, parent, false);
            vh.songName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
            vh.artistName= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        vh.songName.setText(mp3Models.get(position).getTitle());
        //vh.songName.setTypeface(captureFont);
        vh.songName.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        vh.songName.setTextColor(BLACK);
        //vh.songName.setBackgroundColor(parseColor("#333333"));
        vh.songName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);

        //artist name
        vh.artistName.setText(mp3Models.get(position).getArtist());
        vh.artistName.setTextColor(GRAY);
        vh.artistName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,10);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Android Support Library to 23.2.0 cause error: XmlPullParserException Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622438/update-android-support-library-to-23-2-0-cause-error-xmlpullparserexception-bin)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a vector xml drawable.  Those were not supported until v21.  This device is v19.  You need to provide a non-vector drawable for this version

Comment: oh shoot, okay. how do I do that?