# Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After solving a JDK zero value error, now I'm facing this one. I did a little research, but it seems I can't get to the point. Here is the log error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2204)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5069)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1953)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:354)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:689)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at .MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1092)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5069) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1950)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:354) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:689) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at .MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1092) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5069) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm really confused about what it can be, I read and can't get to the error:

My app:gradle is this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {



    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"




    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "me.me2.com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"




    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }






}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.4'


    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'





}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my style folder:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="Divider">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And my mainactivity.class if needed:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView videoView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // VideoView

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.video));
        videoView.requestFocus();

        /**
         * Loop
         */
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView.start();
                mp.setLooping(true);

            }
        });




    }


    public void Login(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FragmentMain.class); 
        startActivity(intent);

       // finish();

    }

    public void Registro(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registro.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The full answer with all the possible solutions lays down [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

IF you're using Gradle Plugin 2.0, you need to make changes in your `gradle`:

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

If you are using Gradle 1.5 you’ll use instead of previus:

```
// Gradle Plugin 1.5  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     // Stops the Gradle plugin's automatic rasterization of vectors
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  
  // Flag to tell aapt to keep the attribute ids around
  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

Check also: [Update Android Support Library to 23.2.0 cause error: XmlPullParserException Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622438/update-android-support-library-to-23-2-0-cause-error-xmlpullparserexception-bin).

Android Support Library Ref.: [Support Vector Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html).

Also update Android Support dependencies from

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
```

as you're already using build-tools in version of `24.0.2`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply if i try to upgrade dependencies from 23.4.0 to 24.2.0 i got this error  "this support library should not use a different version (24) thank the compileSdkVersion (23)"

if i put (vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  )  it marks in grey the vectordrawables and say cannot resolve symbol.

if i try to add generatedDensities it says 

Error:(20, 0) No such property: generatedDensities for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor_Decorated

Comment: change compileSdkVersion to 24. TargetSdkVersion leave as it is

Comment: i cant change the compileSdkVersion to 24 , it dosnt allow me to sync it

i got this 

Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-24' in: C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Comment: so you need to install android-24 package. Open SDK Manager and install missing resources

Comment: ok i updated all with the SDK Manager and dont seem to be working

Comment: what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73486011/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-switchmaterial-switchmateria

Answer (score 35):

If any of the other solutions does not work, you can add this line in your Activity

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

and of course, update your gradle and appcompat to the latest versions. This worked in my case.

Answer (score 24):

None of these worked for me. But this did:

Change

`android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"`

to

`app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_drawable"`

Comment: what should we do for background image?

Comment: any option for android:drawableRight="@drawable/vectorImage" ?

Comment: @MohitMehta have found any solution?

Comment: @aminpinjari did not find any solution so removed vector image from my project and included jpg :)

Comment: Yeah. After I started using android: src =, I started getting this error. Is it really gonna work?

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this issue in Xamarin.Android with Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 24.0.2. Here is how I solved it:

Added the following line to my Application class `OnCreate`:

```
AppCompatDelegate.CompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled = true;
```

Replaced:

```
var upArrow = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this, Resource.Drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
```

With:

```
var upArrow = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(Resources, Resource.Drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material, null);
```

Comment: it is **AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);**

Comment: No need to replace ContextCompact with ResourcesCompat, I think problem with gradle.

Comment: @ArashHatami - as noted in the answer - this is for Xamarin.Android (.NET/C#)

Answer (score 7):

Since this page is the first result of google `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/`, I want to share that this exception might caused by your **foo.xml contains improper code**.

e.g. `foo.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <size android:height="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This xml contains `<size android:height="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />` which compiled successfully but throws exception at Runtime, vary in different app.

Comment: Ran into the same problem when I had `<solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />` in a `drawable`, and ran it on a <API 21 emulator, but accessing attributes in an XML drawable isn't supported on those older android versions. The fact that it worked on newer versions but threw that misleading indirect `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/my_drawable.xml from drawable resource ID` exception on older ones confused me for a while. :/

Answer (score 6):

use like this in your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
     }
  ...
}
```

and this in your build.gradle :

```
android {
    ...

     defaultConfig {
         ....
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

}

and in your xml:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_icon"
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was while running the app on **Kitkat** version I got this runtime crash.

Issue:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        //Change this to true to enable multidex support for Kitkat
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
```

Solution:
//comment the line of vector support

```
android {
        //Change this to true to enable multidex support for Kitkat
         multiDexEnabled true
        //vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i just solved my problem, the problem was my gradle outdated and my sdk , so if anyone is running with this problem just do this steps

1.- Make sure your libs are updated as piotrek1543 says above
2.- Update your sdk if is necesary
3.- Update your gradle files (VERY IMPORTANT)
just go to the project gradle and add this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

then go to your app project > app > graddle > graddlewrapper.properties and add

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

4.- change your compile compileSdkVersion to 24
   and your buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"  (**MAKE SURE YOUR DEPENDENCES ARE UP TO DATE WITH THE SDK**)

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all solutions mentioned above. Nothing worked for me. The only thing worked for me is very simple is to update all support libraries to latest version as this bug has been fixed in it. So i simple did the below thing in gradle file; updated SDK and support to 25.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25"
  defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 25
   }

}
In dependencies 

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically related to your question, but maybe can solve this problem for all that find themselves here while searching for that error.

For me was the problem with SVG file that I have imported into my project. One of the paths in XML has empty `pathData` and that was causing the crash on some devices like Pixel XL, Samsung Galaxy S7,...

So double check imported XML for an image if you are using SVG as your image source.

Comment: I stumble again on this issue and this time was not an empty `pathData` but it was `pathData` too big, so also pay attention for this. Best practice is to remove parts of imported XML and to run it. ;)

Comment: I suggest using tools for optimizing SVGs or even Vector drawables for avoiding this kind of problems. Here are 2 great tools to do that:
https://github.com/svg/svgo
https://github.com/alexjlockwood/avocado

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.

In your Application class, in the onCreate() method, add:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

... and also use `AppCompatImageView` instead of ImageView.

Ex :
BaseApplication.class :

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Your other code here...
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

XML :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/yourIvId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was about using vector drawable.
The spec of the test device was Huawei EVA-L19, Android: Marshmallow

Using `srcCompat` instead of `src` resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was wrong super-type. I added image view dynamically, and used ImageView instead of AppCompatImageView. Choosing the right super class solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the answers above but no success because of clarity most of the time.

Just do this:

1. In the launch_background.xml file, replace **mipmap** with **drawable**
2. Copy the icon image that should be your app icon and paste it in the **drawable** folder

At the end the launch_background.xml file should look like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a big vector file. I used a simplified version of the vector file with the same design and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the kotlin-stdlib dependency from:

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.0"`
to

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.0"`
fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the XML contained `android:endX` that supports from 24 and up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `?attr` inside your drawable, this could be the reason of error.

consider replacing it with `Vector` Drawable so it can be used in all android versions:

Replace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?attr/navigationIconColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

With:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="37dp"
    android:height="5dp"
    android:viewportWidth="37"
    android:viewportHeight="5">
  <path
      android:pathData="M2.5,0h32C35.9,0 37,1.1 37,2.5l0,0C37,3.9 35.9,5 34.5,5h-32C1.1,5 0,3.9 0,2.5l0,0C0,1.1 1.1,0 2.5,0z"
      android:fillColor="?attr/navigationIconColor"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above methods didn’t work for me. I solved it by adding image of every size and used android:src as well it worked.
See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64537207/11669081

Answer (score 0):

for running the app on Kitkat version make use of VectorDrawableCompat like below

```
ivBg.setImageDrawable(VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, R.drawable.ic_bg_minicash_single,context?.theme))
```

No need to change ImageView into AppCompatImageView explicitly AppCompatActivity will automatically convert it.