# Appcompat, crash on start - invalid drawable tag vector

Tags: android, android-support-library

Got the error when launch my app

```
    ...
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
    ...
        Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
```

my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
}
```

I'm not using vector drawables, so there are no related errors in the code. Have tried all possible answers. The app continue crashes on API <21

Comment: What gradle plugin do you have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739743/file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml-from-drawable-resource-id-0x7f020

Comment: And you are not using vector drawables, no, but the support library does

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Do you need an equal sign at `useSupportLibrary = true`?

Comment: Is it necessary? Nevermind, I tried with the sign as well

Comment: I don't know Groovy that well, so maybe not, just referring to the last post, and this one.  They're the same errors... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419596/resourcesnotfoundexception-file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml

Comment: Maybe the same, but I already tried that answer, as you can see in my code

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. In my case the trouble was in the app theme I was applying to the ToolBar. I'm using custom color attribute and inflater can't recognize it, since it point to nowhere