# App crashes in pre lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout

May be silly question but really looking in google for 2hrs.
Actually my app gets crashed in pre lollipop but run well in other versions.the following is the crash report.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class Button
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                                 at .MvpFragment.onCreateView(MvpFragment.java:59)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/custom_button_selected.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200a4
```

I'm using custom background for for button as below:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCompleted"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:text="Completed"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_selected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

custom_button_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="?attr/icon_color"
                android:endColor="?attr/icon_color"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/transparent_color8" />
            <corners
                android:radius="2dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="?attr/icon_color"
                android:startColor="?attr/icon_color"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/transparent_color8" />
            <corners
                android:radius="2dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="?attr/icon_color"
                android:endColor="?attr/icon_color"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/transparent_color8" />
            <corners
                android:radius="2dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Doesn't your `drawable` lays in some resource-v21 folder?

Comment: No it is in res folder@Ekalips

Comment: How i can fix this compatibilty issue for pre lollipo as well as other devices.@Ekalips

Comment: First thing: Why is your `android:startColor` and `android:endColor` referencing same attr? If you want only one color - use `<solid>` tag. Second thing: Try to replace all `?attr/` with `@color/...`

Comment: I got the same issue. if that custom_button_selected.xml file is located in drawable-v21 folder,copy the same file to drawable folder also.

Answer (score 0):

`StateListDrawable` can be used to change state of an button (pressed, focused...) and if you are going to use your `custom_button_selected.xml` as background to change states of your buttton then you are missing `drawable` inside your `selector` particulary inside your `item` tag as it is required. Something like this:

`<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent_color8"> .... </item>` - or whatever color you wanna use

Answer (score 0):

android {defaultConfig { vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true}}

Comment: I have read your problem and please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419596/resourcesnotfoundexception-file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml