# Crash on loading Drawable using VectorDrawableCompat

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

Trying to load Drawable from resources. Getting this traceback and a crash:

```
Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_group_tip, null);



Process: com.microsoft.mobile.polymer.dev1, PID: 16061
                                                                                   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v22/ic_group_tip_1.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f020446
                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:3056)
                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:3005)
                                                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:439)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.TypedArrayUtils.getNamedColor(TypedArrayUtils.java:64)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1791)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1745)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflateInternal(VectorDrawableCompat.java:773)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:657)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:615)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.create(VectorDrawableCompat.java:596)
                                                                                       at com.microsoft.mobile.polymer.groupCreationAndEditing.fragments.AddUsersAndGroupsFragment.disclosureButtonTapped(AddUsersAndGroupsFragment.java:192)
                                                                                       at com.microsoft.mobile.polymer.groupCreationAndEditing.adapters.UsersAndGroupsAdapter$UsersAndGroupsViewHolder$1.onClick(UsersAndGroupsAdapter.java:237)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5272)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21528)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5790)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
                                                                                    Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #9: invalid color state list tag gradient
                                                                                       at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:217)
                                                                                       at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:201)
                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:3052)
                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:3005) 
                                                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:439) 
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.TypedArrayUtils.getNamedColor(TypedArrayUtils.java:64) 
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1791) 
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1745) 
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflateInternal(VectorDrawableCompat.java:773) 
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:657) 
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:615) 
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.create(VectorDrawableCompat.java:596) 
                                                                                       at com.microsoft.mobile.polymer.groupCreationAndEditing.fragments.AddUsersAndGroupsFragment.disclosureButtonTapped(AddUsersAndGroupsFragment.java:192) 
                                                                                       at com.microsoft.mobile.polymer.groupCreationAndEditing.adapters.UsersAndGroupsAdapter$UsersAndGroupsViewHolder$1.onClick(UsersAndGroupsAdapter.java:237) 
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5272) 
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21528) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5790) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1015) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

I was trying to follow to fix loading:
[Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419596/resourcesnotfoundexception-file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml)

Answer (score 0):

You should add [**`setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html#setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(boolean)).

> When enabled, AppCompat can intercept some drawable inflation from the
>   framework, which enables implicit inflation of vector drawables within
>   DrawableContainer resources.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
```

**FYI**

```
Resources$NotFoundException:File res/drawable-v22/ic_group_tip_1.xml
```

This exception is thrown by the resource APIs when a requested resource can not be found. Check your local **`drawable-v22`** section.

Comment: I have already added AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
 in my activity onCreate. Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: Ok I will check.