# Crash APP in Android 5 - android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android

I have the app and in Android 6, 7 everything is ok, but when I can't open an app on android 5. The problem in LOG is:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
> res/drawable-v21/ic_apps_selector.xml from drawable resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f08006a

Please help me with this

In gradle i have one warning but i dont know how to fix it:
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)
Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

Comment: Did you check what is inside `ic_apps_selector.xml` in drawable-v21? It's hard to say anything without more details, but probably you have another drawable folder like drawable-v23 which has another version of ic_apps_selector.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in your gradle and

`static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }`

to your activity.

See [Resources$NotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419596/resourcesnotfoundexception-file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml/41965285)