# Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.test:drawable/back_button with resource ID #0x7f080073

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

I recently added vector drawables (anydpi) to my android studio project in addition to png images (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi)--android studio does this by default now.

I immediately started getting this error:

```
2019-02-10 23:10:25.870 2722-2722/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test, PID: 2722
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.SettingsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.test:drawable/back_button with resource ID #0x7f080073
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2951)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.test:drawable/back_button with resource ID #0x7f080073
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/back_button.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080073
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:847)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:631)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:888)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:827)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:635)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setNavigationIcon(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:599)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(ToolbarActionBar.java:161)
        at com.example.test.SettingsActivity.setUpToolbarAndActionBar(SettingsActivity.java:642)
        at com.example.test.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:159)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:849)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:770)
2019-02-10 23:10:25.870 2722-2722/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1321)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:194)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:122)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1291)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:833)
            ... 27 more
```

The error led to here in my code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_settings);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
int drawable = R.drawable.back_button;
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable); // ERROR IS HERE
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawable);
```

The code above is called in the onCreate of my activity, where I set a custom drawable (R.drawable.back_button) to the back button of the activity.

However, R.drawable.back_button is a drawable resource file which changes the drawable when it is pressed:

```
<selector
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/back">
        </bitmap>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent">
        </bitmap>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I have tried using app:srcCompat instead of and in addition to android:src, but I still get the error.

R.drawable.back is made up of 5 files of different dpi's: anydpi (vector), mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi.

And my gradle settings:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        renderscriptTargetApi 24
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0') { force = true }
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation('com.android.support:design:28.0.0') { force = true }
    implementation('com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0') { force = true }
    implementation('com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0') { force = true }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation("com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0") { force = true }
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Also interesting: when I change the drawable I set in the onCreate to R.drawable.back (directly using the drawable instead of using R.drawable.back_button, which is a resource file), there is no error. So crash seems to be due to using vector drawables in a drawable resource file.

UPDATE:

Another error I am getting:

In R.drawable.back_button, when I only use android:src, I get an error:

```
<bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/back" <!-- ERROR: When using VectorDrawableCompat, you need to use srcCompat-->
    android:tint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

But when I use srcCompat

```
<bitmap <!-- ERROR: required attribute src should be defined-->
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/back"
    android:tint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Using both src and srcCompat doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you try `ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.back_button)`?

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work...

Comment: 1) Drawables with theme attributes
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name);
You'll obtain a styled Drawable as your Activity theme instructs. This is probably what you need.

2) Drawables without theme attributes
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.name, null);

Comment: This did not work either. Perhaps this is a bug?

Comment: remove the png's and add this to your on create  AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code, we need to add the @drawable/back in every drawable folder example "main/res/drawable-xxhdpi", "main/res/drawable-xhdpi” …etc
then only it will work. (i.e every size ex: hdpi, mdpi,xxhdpi..etc)

we can add the back.png in every folder using android studio by following steps

1. click “File” and then Click on "New", then "Image Asset"

[image: options]

2. Change "Asset Type" to "Action Bar and Tab Icons”

[image: Action bar and tab icons]

3. For "Foreground" choose “ClipArt"

[image: clipart]

4. For "Clipart" click and "Choose" button and pick any icon

[image: choose clipart]

5. For "Resource Name" type in your icon file name
   [image: name]

**6. Click Next then all sizes of the images(hdpi, mdpi,xxhdpi..etc)  will be generated**

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable. back_button);
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(icon);
```

and set below to on create

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```