# Error inflating class > com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial

Tags: android, material-components-android

So I use `SwitchMaterial` in one layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial...
```

And Firebase Crashlytics spams me with the following errors for many users

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{...}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file
> line #324: Binary XML file line #324: Error inflating class
> com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial

> Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException File
> res/drawable/abc_switch_thumb_material.xml from drawable resource ID
> #0x7f080047

App theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">...
```

Material dep:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1"
```

What does it mean?

**Update**

I tried to use `Switch` from AndroidX AppCompat library instead and still the same issue with drawable:

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{****.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #324: Binary XML file line #324: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat`

`Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException Drawable ***:drawable/abc_switch_thumb_material with resource ID #0x7f080047`

This is so weird, it works fine for my smartphones though but it's effected 22 my users already

Yes, I have both the following options enabled for release builds

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

But it worked fine all the time for different apps and I never had to add anything to a proguard file to keep drawable of some third party libraries (especially Google libraries) - `abc_switch_thumb_material`

**Update 2**

I just tried to download APK generated by Google Play Console from my AAB file

[image]

I checked `apk\res\drawable\` and found that drawable is available

[image]

This is magic...

But this generated APK is universal and Google Play Consoles generates different APK based on type of device and its Android version, so what happens in this case I don't know

**Update 3**

I will try to use just `Switch` even if Android Studio shows the following warning:

> Use SwitchCompat from AppCompat or SwitchMaterial from Material
> library

But at least I hope my app will stop getting crashed for some users because of it

p.s. devices for which the error happens (Firebase Crashlytics):

[image]

[image]

My `build.gradle` files of that app (if it's helpful in anyway and mb there are some conflicts between libraries)

**Project build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = "1.7.10"
        nav_version = "2.5.1"
        hilt_version = "2.43.2"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.1"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version" // for DataStore

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App module build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
    id "kotlin-parcelize"
    id "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
    id "kotlinx-serialization" // for DataStore
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ***
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 18
        versionName "1.0.15"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: false]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: true]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.2"

    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"

    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"

    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1"

    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.0.0"

    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:5.0.0"

    def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    // Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

    // OkHttp
    implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.0"))
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")

    // Retrofit
    def retrofit = "2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit"

    // Glide
    def glide_version = "4.13.2"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"

    // Pagination
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.1.1"

    // Datastore
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-protobuf:1.4.0"

    implementation "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.15.2"

    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
}
```

Comment: I'm also seeing this when ```PreferenceGroupAdapter``` inflates ```SwitchCompat```, but (so far) only for Nexus 5X running Android 8.1. I suspect it's related to the split APK that Google Play is delivering, somehow getting installed on an incompatible device (backup restoration? 3rd party APK host?). The missing resource in question (```abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012```) has no default density version (only ```mdpi```, ```hdpi```, ```xhdpi```, ```xxhdpi```, and ```xxxhdpi```). Perhaps they've installed a split APK for a higher dpi device onto a lower device? Whatever, I can't recreate it.

Comment: I have opened a bug in the Android Material Library: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/3032

Comment: did you find any fix for this? it is crashing for my users as well

Comment: I have the same issue with `MaterialSwitch`.

Answer (score 8):

the crashes stopped when i switched to using `<Switch>`

both `<SwitchCompat>` and `<SwitchMaterial>` caused crashes in production

Answer (score -3):

i tried to change the android:theme in application manifest to my parent activity name and it worked sucessfully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).