# Get [Unfortunately app stopped working] with Every new project in android studio, But not with

Tags: java, android, project

Hey guys I am new to java and android studio.From day first of android studio i got a weird error in android studio that it does not let me run app on my device.

It always gives this error [Unfortunately app stopped working] whenever i made some app with new package name. But here is the catch i got a project file from my friend and that project just run fine on my device [that too with my code] 
I mean if i simply copy my code and other stuff on my friends android project[if take my friends android project as Base file] it runs without any error.

Now i have to forcefully Reuse that project again and again [that my friend gave me] to write all my codes and run them on my device. I wanted to know Why this issue is not happening with the project of my friend but only happen with all new projects of mine.

I will be very thankful if someone could help me out. Because of this weird error i am unable to test my app with the package name of my choice.

LOGCAT is here

```
09-28 14:29:50.011  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
09-28 14:29:50.011  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16192: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
09-28 14:29:50.011  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
09-28 14:29:50.011  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
09-28 14:29:50.011  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
09-28 14:29:50.011  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16194: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
09-28 14:29:50.011  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
09-28 14:29:50.011  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
09-28 14:29:50.011  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16198: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
09-28 14:29:50.016  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
09-28 14:29:50.016  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
09-28 14:29:50.016  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 453: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
09-28 14:29:50.016  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-28 14:29:50.016  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
09-28 14:29:50.016  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 475: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
09-28 14:29:50.016  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
09-28 14:29:50.031  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob E/VdcInflateDelegate﹕ Exception while inflating <vector>
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
            at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:541)
            at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:478)
            at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:441)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:736)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:359)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:189)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:182)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:717)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:187)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
            at com.lunarpole.hirob.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 14:29:50.031  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-28 14:29:50.031  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fa3c08)
09-28 14:29:50.036  22023-22023/com.lunarpole.hirob E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lunarpole.hirob, PID: 22023
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lunarpole.hirob/com.lunarpole.hirob.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02004f
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02004f
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3422)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1909)
            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:194)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:182)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:717)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:187)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
            at com.lunarpole.hirob.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:986)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3418)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1909)
            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:194)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:182)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:717)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:187)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
            at com.lunarpole.hirob.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you try giving your project to your friend to see if it crashes there?

Comment: Yes gave  it and it didn't crash there.Even he is unable to understand this weird problem

Comment: It only happens whenever i try to make something in a new project with a new package name.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622438/update-android-support-library-to-23-2-0-cause-error-xmlpullparserexception-bin ?

Comment: Thanks a Bunch for all you guys who helped me in this question  I solved this problem by replacing the dependencies 

From 
ependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}

To 

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}

But  Now I wanted to know how can i put these dependencies by default so that every time i open new project and roid studio automatically put these dependencies in gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a Bunch for all you guys who helped me in this question. I solved this problem by replacing the dependencies
    From

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}

To 
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

***Correct Build. Gradle of my Friend***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lunarpole.helloapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

**Wrong Build.gradle file which gave me error**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.lunarpole.beauty"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    }
```

But Now I wanted to know how can i put these dependencies by default so that every time i open new project and roid studio automatically put these dependencies in gradle. How To do that

Comment: Problem with your previous gradle.build is in line:
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
It needs to be 24.2.1.
You can't target SDK 24 and use build tools 23.

Comment: In build tool version list it gives me option of 24.0.2 is it ok if i go with it

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Version is 24.0.2