# E/VdcInflateDelegate: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0

Tags: android, gradle, version-control, android-4.4-kitkat

Following is my Gradle File. Its Working On Marshmallow But Its not Working On KitKat 4.2.2. It returns the following error when I run it on Kitkat.

```
 Exception while inflating <vector>
12-21 17:45:46.235 12303-12303/com.xyz.packagename E/VdcInflateDelegate: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
```

AppCompact is not supporting for the App. If i use Activity instead of Appcompact then it works fine but i need to use AppCompact because integration of Material Design Things.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android 
     {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"


    defaultConfig 
     {
        applicationId "com.xyz.projectName"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes 
    {
        release
        {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

dependencies

 {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'


    // Map
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'


    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help.

Comment: change `buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"` to this `buildToolsVersion "25.1.0"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Android Support Library to 23.2.0 cause error: XmlPullParserException Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622438/update-android-support-library-to-23-2-0-cause-error-xmlpullparserexception-bin)

Comment: I have tried with both solution which is given by @IronMan and @ Saeed Zhiany  but still i am getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

**By Adding below line it work fine for me**

**aaptOptions {
           additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
      }**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"


        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.xyz.project name"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
         /*   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            generatedDensities = []*/
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        // important to run code on kitkat

        aaptOptions {
            additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        // multidex
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'

        // ImageLoader
        compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

        // Map
        //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'

        // Spinner
        compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'

        // Volley
        compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

        //Firebase
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

        //CropImage
        compile project(':CropImage')

    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```