# Update Android Support Library to 25.0.1 cause error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

This is my changes:

```
// compileSdkVersion 25  
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

// compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"  
 //compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
```

My Log:

```
01-30 12:05:33.549 5299-5299/com.firstpost E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.firstpost/com.firstpost.SearchActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2810)
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1522)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
                                                                 at com.firstpost.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:68)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                              Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:913)
                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:854)
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2807)
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1522) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374) 
                                                                 at com.firstpost.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:68) 
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203) 
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `abc_ic_ab_back_material` image absent in your app folder

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya not absent . I have checked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622438/update-android-support-library-to-23-2-0-cause-error-xmlpullparserexception-bin/35624744

Comment: Thanks @IntelliJAmiya I have already go through many answers . but problem not solved.

Comment: show your `corresponding` xml and `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya basically my code is running fine above jelly bean. when i run it at jelly bean than i got above error. above stack trace came when i do this :-  Drawable up = DrawableCompat.wrap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha));
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(up); Now i have changed code like this way  :     if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }   than i can get click event  by this method onOptionsItemSelected()

Comment: use `buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya  my problem is solved using above i explained but now I am getting black image of back button. I want to white , can you plz tell me . Thanks

Comment: okay . `Binary XML file line #17:` please post your victim xml and `styles.xml` under `values` folder

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay">

Comment: <style name="PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

Comment: nope . i want to know `parent` theme name

Comment: please add this in your question section

Comment: To change icon to white add the following to toolbar  `app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"` You may need to do it in 2 steps, creating the style in styles,  similarly to how you did the popupTheme.

Answer (score 0):

// i dont know this is right way or not . i handle this problem using following code :-

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

before i am using this way to set back button icon to navigation

//Drawable up = DrawableCompat.wrap(AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.back_arrow_new));
        // toolbar.setNavigationIcon(up);